# Why remaining gas increase after some opcodes

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, opcode

I use debug api of go ethereum to get traces of transactions. The api document shows that field `gas` represents the amount of gas remaining in the transaction at the current step of execution and field `gasCost` represents the amount of gas consumed by the current opcode being executed. I found after opcodes `RETURN,REVERT,STOP`, the remaining gas increased and the gas cost of `CALL,DELEGATECALL,STATICCALL` is much higher than the difference between the remaining gas of current opcode and the remaining gas of the next opcode. 
For example,

```
[...,{"op":"RETURN", "gas":116928, "gasCost":0},{"op":...., "gas":118834,...},...]
```

```
[{"pc": 18928, "op": "STATICCALL", "gas": 437178, "gasCost": 430388},{"pc": 0, "op": "PUSH1", "gas": 427782, "gasCost": 3}]
```

The gas refund will return at the end of the transaction, but the RETURN opcode in the example is in the middle part. Why does the remaining gas increase after RETURN/STOP/REVERT? The gasCost of STATICCALL looks like gas limit.